# Efficient way to handle below query? in SQLServer or PostgreSql (Self join)

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, self-join

I have an employee table as below

[image: select * from employee]

I need to select employee_id, manager_id, result. result should have true or false depends on below conditions.

1. If the employee is manager for someone then true
2. If the employee has a manager then true

I came up with a query, but I need to know if there are any other better way to do it.
This is my query

```
with manager  as
(
select distinct manager_id from employee where manager_id is not null
)
select 
e.employee_id, e.manager_id , m.manager_id, 
case when e.manager_id is not null then true
     when m.manager_id is not null then true 
     else false
end as Result
from employee e left join manager m  on e.employee_id = m.manager_id
```

and the result should come like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
select
  e.employee_id,
  e.manager_id,
  (
    e.manager_id is not null
    or
    exists(select 1 from employee m where m.manager_id=e.employee_id)
  ) as result
from employee e;
```

Comment: Please note that this would benefit from index on `employee(manager_id)`.

Comment: comparing with my query, will this work efficiently?(fast)? how?

Comment: @Kavi it depends on the data volume. You can use `SET STATISTICS IO ON, TIME ON` to detect performance metric.

Comment: @Kavi . . . This is faster -- it really doesn't depend on anything.  There is no additional overhead for removing duplicates.  `select distinct` requires additional processing.

Comment: thanks for your inputs. I need one more help, is there any reference to build a faster query. because every time I managed to find the solution, but my query is not faster. what are the possible ways to build an efficient query?

Comment: @Kavi, the best way is  always to test it with real data :-) and with the time, you will get more experiences in writing SQL. You can always double check your solutions in places like StackOverflow.